# Buy X Get Y for CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob

Just wondering if anyone knows of a discount plugin for CartThrob where you can place a free product in the cart if someone buys another product?

I'd like to set in the admin a discount so that if a person buys product X then product Y will automatically get added to the cart for free.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late now, but have you tries here: https://github.com/CartThrob/cartthrob-discounts-buy_x_get_y